# Iterate over Guava ImmutableList in Scala

Tags: scala, guava

I'm having trouble iterating over a `ImmutableList` from Guava in Scala. The only reason I'm working with them is because I'm working with code written in Java that uses the Guava API. However, the compiler doesn't seem to like it. Here's my code:

```
for (blockData: IBlockData <- block.P.a) {
  *insert actions here*
}
```

The compiler errors with this:

```
Error:(24, 43) value filter is not a member of com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList[net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.IBlockData]
for (blockData: IBlockData <- block.P.a) {
                      ^
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `Scala`s `for` expression the object has to implement `flatMap` and `filter` which `guava` collections do not. `Scala` comes bundled with `Java` converters, this should work:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
for (blockData: IBlockData <- block.P.a.asScala) {
  *insert actions here*
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should have thought of using `JavaConverters`. I thought `JavaConversions` would work somehow :P

Comment: @TheReturningVoid Yes, `JavaConversions` should work as well. `JavaConverters` are simply preferred.